# Is there a object level TTL in RIAK?

Tags: riak

Is there a way to set a document level TTL for every object that we store in RIAK?

For example, if i want to store "value" for a "key" in RIAK, can i set a TTL of 30 seconds on that key so that the element expires on the 31st second?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't store a different TTL for each object, but if you're using the Bitcask or in-memory backend you can set a "global" TTL which is applied to all objects stored.

See: [FAQ: How can I automatically expire a key from Riak?](http://docs.basho.com/riak/1.4.0rc1/cookbooks/faqs/developing-faq/#how-can-i-automatically-expire-a-key-from-riak)

In the app config you'd have:

```
{bitcask, [
    {data_root, "data/bitcask"},
    {expiry_secs, 30} %% Expire after 30 secs
 ]},
```

Comment: Please note that you also can use the multi backend option to define multiple bitcask backends, each with its own TTL setting.